# How to create 2 classes in .m file?

Tags: objective-c

Hi I am very new to Objective-C with Java/C# Background. In Java I can create 2 classes in Single Java Class file like as follows

```
class class1{
}

class class2{
}
```

How Can I do that in Objective-C ?

I already have .m file with name util. How can I add one more class ? sorry for my newbie numenclature!

Thanks

Comment: @woz not necessarily.  Sometimes it's more appropriate to have two classes in the same file.

Comment: Not really the forum for this discussion but I would really like to hear what benefits this would give. If two classes share the same files why bother separating the classes at all? It will also mean adding dependencies to two classes even if you only need one. At the surface at least it seems to fly in the face of OOP.

Comment: @nickfalk What about asking Apple? Open NSString.h to get an example. More abstract: When to classes work together very close, it can reduce the number of dependencies. You can have the same reason, if you have small private subclasses.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this question. Seems like a solid technical question from a new SO user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in the same way:

```
@interface Class1
@end

@interface Class2
@end

@implementation Class1
@end

@implementation Class2
@end
```

Probably you would like to move interfaces to the header file.